# How to detect if user clicked with mouse or touched an item in createJS

Tags: jquery, html, touch, createjs, easeljs

I'm making a game using HTML5/createJS, the thing is that I must know if the user clicked on a item or used touch to tap on it because the time to answer matters.

The code is here, I enabled the touch in createJS then the click function works for both clicking and tap.

```
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
item.addEventListener("click", startCounter);

startCounter = function(evt)
{
  console.log(evt.isTouch)
  //IF CLICK { }

  //IF TAP { }
}
```

evt.isTouch gives me always false on my touchscreen laptop if I use the mouse or tap on the screen.

Comment: Check out the event you get passed in the startCounter. It should be different for touch and tap.

Comment: Nop it isn't. Always: Object { type: "click", target: Object, currentTarget: Object, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: true, cancelable: false, timeStamp: 1447324467551, defaultPrevented: false, propagationStopped: false, immediatePropagationStopped: false, 9 more… }

Comment: EaselJS MouseEvents contain a `nativeEvent` property, which is the actual event generated by the user. The native event type should be different ("click" vs "touchend" for example). Touch events should also have different properties such as a "pointerId". http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/MouseEvent.html#property_nativeEvent

Comment: I have a laptop with touchscreen. Every property gives me the same values even the isTouch gives me always false. Sadly, It is not bullet proof. It doesn't work for all devices.